# Send data from Android app to lotus notes database

Tags: android, json, lotus-notes

I work in Android app which I extract data from lotus notes database and save this as a json file. This works fine.

In the second step I'm able to send data from my Android app to IBM lotus notes (create a new mask if the universal id doesn't exist else update a masque). This works fine.

In third step I want to send data from my Android app to IBM lotus notes ( I mean create a document in a workflow (under mask) not in a mask.any idea please?

I use REST API and json in my project.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  I understand that you are using the word "mask" to mean what we call a "Form" in the English-speaking Notes world, but even with that I don't understand what "create a document ina workflow (under Form) not in any Form" means. The best I can come up with is "under Form" may mean that you want to create a response document, and "not in any mask" may mean that you want to create the response document without using a Form. I see no reason why you can't do that, but I don't understand why you would want to - so I think I am probably still not understanding.

Comment: I think you need to show us several things: 1. A picture of what you want the result to be in the Notes database. 2. Your best effort so far at creating the code for your third step, along with a description of what happens when you run it, and what you want to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send data from your Android app to a Domino database using REST calls, with JSON as the payload. The REST call will then create a new document in the Domino database, using a specific form. Is that correct?

There are a couple of ways you can create your API endpoint on the Domino server.

One way is to use an "X-agent" (actually an XPage) to read the JSON payload).
You can read more here: http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/domino_rest_xpages_part1.html
You can also write an agent (Java or Lotusscript) that you then call, passing the payload to it. This is what I usually do.

In your agent you read the incoming payload, create the new document and populate the fields on it with the values from the JSON payload.
I have created a Lotusscript class that will make it easy to read the incoming payload: http://blog.texasswede.com/free-code-class-to-read-url-name-value-pairs/